# Run OCI CLI command from dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a question about Oracle OCI CLI. I create an image ([LINK](https://hub.docker.com/r/juliovg/oracle-oci-19)) that contain all necessary to start working with oracle cloud. You have to modify config file just to start using all from Oracle cloud.

Or you can set your ora cloud environment with:

```
oci setup config
```

but i want to to execute some OCI commands with dockerfile, but is really complex, i can't do it work. I'm doing this

```
FROM juliovg/oracle-oci-19
ENV HOME_DIR=/root \ 
CODE_DIR=/root/sample/code \
BUCKET_NAME=Code
WORKDIR $HOME_DIR
RUN rm -rf $HOME_DIR/.oci
RUN wget "<.OCI_FILE_URL_UPLOADED_INTO_A_BUCKET>/my_key.tar.gz"
RUN tar -xvf my_key.tar.gz && rm -rf my_key.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p $CODE_DIR
RUN cd $CODE_DIR
RUN touch my_file.txt

RUN oci os bucket create -c <MY_COPARTMENT> --name <NEW_BUCKET_NAME>
```

And this is the error -->

[image]

I need execute some OCI commands at the begging with RUN or CMD (i try both)

Notes: OCI_FILE_URL_UPLOADED_INTO_A_BUCKET is a zip file that contains the configuration made with another computer, the idea is share the same key with several users , when the use the **juliovg/oracle-oci-19** with another thinks

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like path issue, dockerfile RUN command call executable like `/bin/sh -c executable`. so better to give the full path of the executable like `RUN /root/bin/oci -v`.

```
FROM juliovg/oracle-oci-19
ENV HOME_DIR=/root \ 
CODE_DIR=/root/sample/code \
BUCKET_NAME=Code
WORKDIR $HOME_DIR
RUN rm -rf $HOME_DIR/.oci
RUN mkdir -p $CODE_DIR
RUN cd $CODE_DIR
RUN touch my_file.txt
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
ENV LANG=en_US.utf-8
RUN /root/bin/oci -v
RUN /root/bin/oci os bucket create -c MY_COPARTMENT --name NEW_BUCKET_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider that the container may not be aware of the location of the executable of OCI CLI. You should give it the full path of OCI CLI in the Dockerfile